# Why can't I edit this post?

Tags: support, editing

Strangely, the edit link is missing from this post when I tried to reformat the wall of unformatted text in his post...

[How do I access a digital camera drive via usb after safely removing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/how-do-i-access-a-digital-camera-drive-via-usb-after-safely-removing-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple circumstances under which you won't be able to suggest an edit; in this case, it's because there was [another suggested edit on that post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/539) waiting to be approved. It's accepted now, so the edit link should be back